# PostgreSQL foreign key violation inside transaction

Tags: postgresql

I have a function with several queries inside, like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.myfunction(winningid integer, losingid integer)
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
begin

update partecipants set id_be=winningId where id_be=losingId;
...
many other updates and deletes regarding other tables
...

delete from business_entity where id_be=losingId;

end;
$function$
;
```

There is a foreign key between partecipants and business_entity:

```
ALTER TABLE partecipants ADD CONSTRAINT partecipants_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_be) REFERENCES business_entity(id_be)
```

Sometimes (like 1 in 1000 times) this function hangs with error:

```
error: update or delete on table "business_entity" violates foreign key constraint "partecipants_fk" on table "partecipants"
detail:
   'Key (id_be)=(315017) is still referenced from table "partecipants".
```

If I run the same function a second time, ends without error.

How is this possible?

As a background information, other processes are using (often also with locks) the tables involved in the function while is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concurrent transactions could add or modify rows in `partecipants` between your `UPDATE` and your `DELETE` so that the latter fails.

If you want to avoid that, do both in a single statement:

```
WITH dummy AS (
   update partecipants set id_be=winningId where id_be=losingId
)
delete from business_entity where id_be=losingId;
```

Comment: Thanks Laurenz! I thinks this query is the solution, but do you know other possible causes? Because the function lasts at most a few seconds so is almost impossible that another process makes an "undo" for the update in a window so little. Just asking beacuse I'm in trouble debugging

Comment: "Only a few seconds" and "almost impossible" is the stuff that [race conditions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) are made of.